# Fade IN sound with Actionscript 3.0

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, audio, fade

I have managed to fade OUT sound with this code and plugins from GreenSock:

```
import com.greensock.TweenLite;
import com.greensock.TweenMax;

var snd = new buller();
var channel:SoundChannel = snd.play(0,999);

TweenMax.to(channel, 1, {volume:0, onComplete:snd.stop});
```

What I can't do is fading IN the sound. Have tried to set an initial sound level but can't make it work. Appreciate any help I can get.

Comment: I wonder how did you make it fade out as far as **SoundChannel** does not actually have a **volume** property. Most probably the **volume** part is ignored and audio is stopped in 1 second. That's why fade in does not work, because fade out shouldn't work either.

Comment: Hehe, right, the tween should address channel.soundTransform and not just the channel. The reason why you don't hear anything when you try to fade in is that the sound stops onComplete of your first tween - you have to play() it again before you fade in

Comment: Thank you for replies! I just figured it out myself. Don't know why fading out worked without "var trans:SoundTransform = new SoundTransform(X, X);". Maybe it sets a value = 1 as default if volume is not defined?

Answer (score 0):

```
var snd = new buller();
var channel:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();
var St::SoundTransform = new SoundTransform();
var TimerFade:Timer = new Timer(1,100);

//set the initial sound volume
St.volume = 1;

//play the sound
channel = snd.play(0,0,St);

//Fade in/out the sound
TimerFade.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER,VolumeHandler);
TimerFade.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE,StopSound);
TimerFade.start();


private function VolumeHandler(e:TimerEvent):void{
  var Lastpos:Number = channel.position;
  channel.stop();
  St.volume -= 0.1;
  channel = snd.play(Lastpos,0,St);
}

private function VolumeHandler(e:TimerEvent):void{
  channel.stop();
}
```